# Different heights of hamburger menu lines

Tags: html, css

I have a weird problem where hamburger menu line height differ from each other.
The middle one is different than the top and bottom even though they have the same properties.

```css
 .hamburger{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid black;    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }

    /* Mid hamburger line*/
    .hamburger > div{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: black;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    /* Top bot line*/
    
    .hamburger > div:before,
    .hamburger > div:after{
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: -10px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background: inherit;
    }
    
    /* moves line down */
    
    .hamburger > div::after{
        top: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="hamburger"><div></div></div>
```

[Hamburger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39VnS.jpg)

Comment: It shows ok to me. You can increase the height to `3px` on pseudo elements.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I also made hamburger like you're approach im my last project and I had the same problem. Now it shows ok on mozilla, maybe it depends on browser.

Comment: I'm using google chrome. Increasing the height to 3px also shows the same thing just bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Please use right approach to make hamburger.
CSS:-

```
.hamburger {border: 1px solid #000; display: inline-block;padding:6px;}
.hamburger div {height:2px; background:#000; width:24px; margin: 3px;}
```

HTML:-

```
    <button class="hamburger">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</button>
```

Comment: Also tried this, still the same result. Thank you for replying.

Comment: It is working fine on my browser and your code also too.
If all of these code is not working fine on your browser It seems like your browser is on zooming mode. Please press key CTRL+0 to make browser mode on 0% or Please attach screenshot of you complete browser screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hamburger{
  border:1px solid #111;
  display: inline-block;
  padding:5px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
.hamburger div{
  height:3px;
  background:#000;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, I still have difference between the line as the picture I showed. Thank you anywyays.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine on my browser and your code also too.
If all the code are not working fine on your browser It seems like your browser is on zooming mode. Please press key CTRL+0 to make browser mode on 0% or Please attach screenshot of you complete browser screenshot.